# Problem with thread implementation

Tags: android

I have a Start button to start my function for downloading data(**startdownload()).**
When the start button click i have placed a text view that shows data is dowmload started and when download completed the same text view show download completed .
Download function is placed under a thread.

```
start_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {                       

                Status.setText("Download Started");

                Thread t = new Thread(){      
                    public void run() {                  
                        startdownload();                                                   
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {                                              
                            public void run() {                                 
                                Status.setText("Download Completed");
                                }                
                            });             
                        }};           
                        t.start(); 
            }
        });
```

Also i have a stop button to stop  downloading data,which stop the thread and shows download stopped using the same text view as above mentioned.the stop button code is as below

```
stop_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {           
                onStop();
                Status.setText("Download Stopped");             

            }

public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        isRunning = false;  
        }
```

The problem is that when i click start button the text view shows download started but when clicked stop button before completely dowloading the data it shows download stopped
in the text view first and after some time it shows download completed.....

Please any one verify that is there any problem with my thread implementation procedure...
I think thats why it shows download completed even when i stoped the thread using stop button....Please help me......

Comment: Please show the code that how you are stopping the thread.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can update UI from thread so please try to use the handler.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually stop thread? Or it continues to run after you press stop button?
You can use flag `isStopped` and in thread:

```
if (!isStopped) {                                                 
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {                                              
        public void run() {                                 
            Status.setText("Download Completed");
        }                
    });             
}
```

and set `isStopped` to true in stop_button.

Comment: I want to stop the thread when stop button click.No need to continue

Comment: @arun, than check Egor's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171898/problem-with-thread-implementation/7172213#7172213)

Answer (score 1):

If `onStop()` is the `Activity.onStop()` callback method, then you should not call it. It has nothing to do with your downloading thread, and anyway it's just a system callback that is called by system. Actually, stopping a thread by yourself is not recommended, the `Thread.stop()` method is deprecated, as you may know. It's easy to "stop" a thread that is performing some operations in a loop: you just drop the flag controlling the loop, result is that the thread keeps on running, but it's doing nothing. Your application architecture doesn't let you stop your thread, cause you're just running a task. Post your downloading code and it will be more clear what you're doing and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Arun, what kind of sample? Did you read my answer carefully? I'd recommend you to read this post: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html, it has some useful info about implementing multithreading in Android